# Make a new list of objects with added properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following two arrays for example:

```
Employees = [
  { id: 1, name: Ahmed, age: 22 },
  { id: 2, name: hassan, age: 43 },
  { id: 3, name: john, age: 44 },
  { id: 4, name: salem, age: 66 }
]

b = [{ emp_id: 1, name: Ahmed }, { emp_id: 4, name: salem }]
```

Now I want a new array that is same as employees but a new property added which isSelected. If the emp_id in array b exists in employees array add a property isSelected : true else false
For example:

```
MyNewList = [
  { id: 1, name: Ahmed, age: 22, isSelected: true },
  { id: 2, name: hassan, age: 43, isSelected: false },
  { id: 3, name: john, age: 44, isSelected: false },
  { id: 4, name: salem, age: 66, isSelected: true }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) over the first array and assign `isSelected` by checking if [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) of the elements in `b` match the currently iterated object's id.

```js
const employees = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Ahmed', age: 22 },
  { id: 2, name: 'hassan', age: 43 },
  { id: 3, name: 'john', age: 44 },
  { id: 4, name: 'salem', age: 66 }
];

const b = [{ emp_id: 1, name: 'Ahmed' }, { emp_id: 4, name: 'salem' }];

const newList = employees.map((e) => (
  {
    ...e,
    isSelected: b.some(({ emp_id }) => emp_id === e.id)
  }
));


console.log(newList);
```

Alternatively you could create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of `emp_id`s from `b` and assign `isSelected` by checking if the [`Set.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) the currently iterated `id`.

```js
const employees = [{ id: 1, name: 'Ahmed', age: 22 }, { id: 2, name: 'hassan', age: 43 }, { id: 3, name: 'john', age: 44 }, { id: 4, name: 'salem', age: 66 }];
const b = [{ emp_id: 1, name: 'Ahmed' }, { emp_id: 4, name: 'salem' }];

const empIds = new Set(b.map(({ emp_id }) => emp_id));
const newList = employees.map((e) => (
  {
    ...e,
    isSelected: empIds.has(e.id)
  }
));


console.log(newList);
```

see also:

- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)
- [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 2):

I would encourage you to look into documentation for object spread as well as array methods such as find, map, and filter. You'll encounter those a lot in the future.

To answer the question, something like this would probably work:

```js
MyNewList = Employees.map((employee) => ({
    ...employee,
    isSelected: b.find((selectedEmployee) => selectedEmployee.emp_id === employee.id) !== undefined,
}))
```

Explanation: The `...employee` is object spread. You'll use this a lot I suggest you look into it. It puts all the properties of the original object into the new one. Then we add a new `isSelected` property, and we use `b.find` to see if this employee has an id in list `b`. We use `!== undefined` because if the find is undefined, the employee is NOT in the list.

Comment: is there any other good way to write this code: `setDrawerList(listEmployess.map((x) => { if (x.id === item.id) { return { ...x, isSelected: true };}
return x;}))}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
const Employees=[
  {id :1 , name:'Ahmed',age:22},
  {id :2 , name:'hassan',age:43},
  {id :3 , name:'john',age: 44},
  {id :4, name:'salem',age:66} ]

const b=[{emp_id :1 , name:'Ahmed'},{emp_id :4, name:'salem'} ];

const selectedEmployee = Employees.map((employee) => {
  if(b.find(item => item.emp_id === employee.id)) {
    employee.selected = true;
  } 
  else employee.selected = false;
  return employee;
});

console.log(selectedEmployee);
```

As pointed out by the @GuillaumeBrunerie The above code will modify the original array. The immutable solution would be:

```js
const Employees=[
  {id :1 , name:'Ahmed',age:22},
  {id :2 , name:'hassan',age:43},
  {id :3 , name:'john',age: 44},
  {id :4, name:'salem',age:66} ]

const b=[{emp_id :1 , name:'Ahmed'},{emp_id :4, name:'salem'} ];

const selectedEmployee = Employees.map((employee) => ({...employee, isSelected: !!b.find(item => item.emp_id === employee.id)}));

console.log(selectedEmployee);
```

Comment: This will change the original array, which is probably unwanted.

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie you're right. This is mutating the original array props.

Answer (score 0):

same as pilchard's answer with a `if` - `else`  change ....

```js
const Employees = [
  { id: 1, name: "Ahmed", age: 22 },
  { id: 2, name: "hassan", age: 43 },
  { id: 3, name: "john", age: 44 },
  { id: 4, name: "salem", age: 66 },
];

const b = [
  { emp_id: 1, name: "Ahmed" },
  { emp_id: 4, name: "salem" },
];

const newList = Employees.map((emp) => {
  if (b.some((x) => x.emp_id === emp.id)) {
    return {...emp, isSelected : true}
  } else {
    return {...emp, isSelected : false}
  }
});

console.log(newList);
console.log(Employees);
```

Comment: This will change the original array, which is probably unwanted.